# Help on a system of nonlinear ODEs

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

I'm currently working on a nonlinear system of ODE's of the following form:
$$f''(x) = F\left(f(x),f'(x),g(x),g'(x)g''(x)\right) $$
$$g''(x) = F(g(x),g'(x),f(x),f'(x),f''(x)) $$
with given initial boundary conditions for $f,g,f'$ and $g'$ at $x=0$. Since the system is quite complex and nonlinear, I'm pretty sure that a numerical method is needed in order to evaluate $f(x)$ and $g(x)$. For instance, the first equation is written as:
$$f''\left\{ \left[A+\frac{Bg'}{\sqrt{1+g'^2}}\right] \left(\frac{g+2gf'^2}{\left(1+f'^2\right)^{3/2}}\right) - \frac{3Bff'\sqrt{1+g'^2}}{\left(1+f'^2\right)^{5/2}} \right\} = \left[A+\frac{Bf'}{\sqrt{1+f'^2}}\right]\sqrt{1+g'^2} + Cg - \\ B\left[\frac{f'\sqrt{1+g'^2}}{\left(1+f'^2\right)^{3/2}} + \frac{fg'g''}{\sqrt{1+g'^2}\left(1+f'^2\right)^{3/2}}+\frac{f'gg''}{\sqrt{1+f'^2}\left(1+g'^2\right)^{3/2}}\right]- \left[A+\frac{Bg'}{\sqrt{1+g'^2}}\right]\frac{gf'}{\sqrt{1+f'^2}} $$
where $A,B$ and $C$ are constants and the dependence on $x$ is omitted by simplicity. The second equation of the system is obtained simply by substituting all $f$ (and their derivatives) by $g$ (and their derivatives).

My doubt is on which numerical method should I adopt to solve the system? I have some experience with the RK4 method to solve second order ODEs, which is similar to a system of ODEs, but in this case, it looks different given that $f''(x)$ is a function of $g''(x)$ and vice-versa, which looks recursive to program. Any help provided will be very appreciated. Thank you in advance!

EDIT: The equations arise from the Euler-Lagrange equations of the following functional:
$$J=\int_0^H{\left\{\left[A+\frac{Bf'}{\sqrt{1+f'^2}}\right]f\sqrt{1+g'^2} + \left[A+\frac{Bg'}{\sqrt{1+g'^2}}\right]g\sqrt{1+f'^2} + Cfg   \right\}dx} $$

Comment: $f''(x)$ depends on $g''(x)$ which again depends on $f''(x)$ so you basically have an equation $f''(x) = G(\ldots, f''(x))$ and similar for $g''(x)$ (if we assume we know the other terms which we do when solving). One possibility is to first rewrite this as a system of first order equations by introducing $h_0 = f(x), h_1 = f'(x), h_2 = g(x), h_3= g'(x)$. This could then be solved with a first order ODE solver + a root finder to determine $h_1'(x)$ and $h_3'(x)$ by solving those non-linear equations at every step (or solve analytically for $f''(x)$ in terms of $g''(x)$ and use this).

Comment: Thank you @Winther, if I get this right then I'd have the two original equations: $h'1 = F(h_0,h_1,h_2,h_3,h'_3)$ and $h'_3 = F(h_0,h_1,h'_1,h_2,h_3)$, plus two more equations in which $h_1=h'_0$ and $h_3=h'_2$.  But again it looks a recursive assignement for me, do you have any suggestion on which solver/method I could implement in a program? Thank you again

Comment: It's recursive in the same way $x = 2 - x$ is. This gives $x = 2 - (2- (\ldots))$ if you recurse, but if you solve the equation you simply have $x=1$. I'm suggesting you try to solve for $f''(x)$ by eliminating $g''(x)$. It looks like this is possible analytically (these terms seem to enter "lineary"). If so then great, you have a simple first order system. If not then one must solve this numerically (e.g. Newtons method or similar).

Comment: In fact, they are not that linear so I can't isolate one term from another, I'll always have the dependence of $f''(x)$ on $g''(x)$ and vice-versa. I'll take a look at Newton's method to solve this system then.

Comment: Hmmm. But don't we, schematically, have $af'' = b + cg''$? And $f$ and $g$ enter symmetrically in the Lagrangian so the EOM for $g$ should be that of $f$ with $f,g$ interchanged, i.e. $\tilde{a}g'' = \tilde{b} + \tilde{c}f''$. Doesn't this allow us to solve for $f''$ and $g''$ in terms of $a,b,c,\tilde{a},\tilde{b},\tilde{c}$?

Comment: Thank you @Winther, I wasn't seeing it before but i think it's clear now. I'll proceed in this manner and try to solve it numerically. Thanks!